# Difference between Jstack and gcore when generating Core Dumps?

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, java-threads

We all know that Core Dumps are an essential diagnostic tools for analysing various processes in Unix . I know both jstack  and gcore  are both used for generating Javacore files or Core Dumps but I have a doubt that Gcore is mainly used for Processes and Jstack is used for threads .

As from an Operating System perspective Process and Threads though interrelated (Process comprises of Threads only) they are relatively different from each other w.r.t memory/speed/execution . So is that gcore  will diagnose the process and jstack will analyse the threads in that process ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCore act at OS level and you got a dump of native code that is currently running. From a java point of view, it is not really understandable.

JStack get you the stack trace at VM level (the java stack) of all thread your application have. You can find from that what is the real java code executed at a point.

Clearly, GCore is almost never used (too low level, native code...). Only really strange issue with native library or stuff like that will perhaps need this kind of tool.

There is also jmap that can generate a hprof file which is the heap data from you VM. A tool like '[Memory Analyser Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)' can open the hprof, and you can drill down on what was going on (on memory side).
If your VM crash because of a OutOfMemory, you can also set parameter to get the hprof when the event occurs. It helps to understand why (too many users, A DB query that fetch too much data...)

Last thing is the fact that you can add a debug option when your start your VM, so that you can connect to it, and put debug on running process. It can help if you have some strange issue that you are not able to reproduce in your local environment.

Comment: I assume from the above that gcore is useful for Core Dump and Jstack is for Thread Dump . A difference between the two can be found in the link .  https://middlewarebyashok.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/heap-dump-and-threaddump-and-core-dump-explanations/